# Running dependant templates from Cloud Function in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions, apache-beam

Is it possible to run two or more dependant templates in sequence using cloud function? My function triggers running of first template the moment any file gets dropped in a particular bucket.
What I need to achieve is to run the second template only after first template gets successfully executed.
I would like to keep the execution order like this :
Template-1 -> (If successfully executed) -> Template-2 ---likewise I can have 'n' number of templates to execute in sequence.
Any leads how to achieve the same using cloud function?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to organize this as a single streaming pipeline continuously ingesting files from the bucket using watchForNewFiles(), rather than separate pipelines triggered by a cloud function and by each other?

Comment: Yes,there is a specific reason behind this. My first pipeline should be triggered by file arrival. This pipeline will load the respective table. Now once that particular table will be loaded with the source file data then only I will have to run some Big queries which is of more than 2000 lines in length performing lots of transformations over the table loaded by source file data.I couldn't find any way to organise this as a single pipeline.

Comment: Okay. Do I remember correctly that your use case would be possible to organize as a single pipeline, if only BigQueryIO.write() returned a result that can be usefully sequenced with other steps in a pipeline?

Comment: Yes :-) if somehow I get the completion status of BigQueryIO.write() as 'Success' then using that status probably I can sequence other steps of pipeline having one as running those transformation queries.